# Understanding Faster RCNN processing

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I run through the [code](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) of Faster RCNN for the better understanding of the implementation.

I used gdb to debug C++ code behind the python interface and I can go through line by line to C++ codes.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf) (page 4, first para) mentioned the split of Convolutional Map to 2k scores and 4k coordinates.

That is implemented using [this prototxt](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/models/pascal_voc/VGG16/faster_rcnn_alt_opt/stage1_rpn_train.pt) as

```
   layer {
      name: "rpn_conv/3x3"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "conv5_3"
      top: "rpn/output"
      param { lr_mult: 1.0 }
      param { lr_mult: 2.0 }
      convolution_param {
      num_output: 512
      kernel_size: 3 pad: 1 stride: 1
      weight_filler { type: "gaussian" std: 0.01 }
      bias_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 }
     }
   }

    layer {
      name: "rpn_cls_score"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "rpn/output"
      top: "rpn_cls_score"
      param { lr_mult: 1.0 }
      param { lr_mult: 2.0 }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 18   # 2(bg/fg) * 9(anchors)
        kernel_size: 1 pad: 0 stride: 1
        weight_filler { type: "gaussian" std: 0.01 }
        bias_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "rpn_bbox_pred"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "rpn/output"
      top: "rpn_bbox_pred"
      param { lr_mult: 1.0 }
      param { lr_mult: 2.0 }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 36   # 4 * 9(anchors)
        kernel_size: 1 pad: 0 stride: 1
        weight_filler { type: "gaussian" std: 0.01 }
        bias_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 }
      }
    }
```

But I go through the code and that is actually implemented under `cudnn_conv_layer.cpp and cudnn_conv_layer.cu`.

After passing through these `rpn_cls_score and rpn_bbox_pred` layers, I can see the output blob shapes are 
capacity 4 = {1, 18, 36, 49}
capacity 4 = {1, 36, 36, 49}, so it splitted scores and boxes.

(1)How can I understand the process it went through so that 256 or 512 Dimension is splitted into {1, 18, 36, 49} and {1, 36, 36, 49}. There are `lr_mult`, but I even can't find how `lr_mult` is used?

(2)Then Page 5 first column discussed about Loss implementation, I can't find the source how this SGD loss minimization is implemented inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

**It would be better to try some basic tutorials on CNN and Caffe first. Directly jumping into Caffe implementation without knowing background theory might lead to more confusion.**

Whatever region of prototxt you showed is just 3 layers of Convolution.

1. 512-plane input feature maps are convolved with 18 filters to get 18-plane output feature maps in layer "rpn_cls_score". Same 512-plane input feature maps are convolved with 36 filters to get 36-plane output feature maps in layer "rpn_bbox_pred".

Both these layers are convolution layers.

See the CPU implementation : https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp

lr_mult is a learning-rate multiplication factor. In your solver.prototxt, there will be a base_lr. It is multiplied with lr_mult of each layer to get the effective learning rate of that layer. It is a part of parameter update and it is hidden from the user. (That is the beauty of machine learning frameworks)

2. Once again, entire backward pass and parameter update are done by the Caffe in background. User need not worry about it. Since you are looking for the implementation, See SGD here : https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp